# remove last and eight table cell in all tables row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table where I want to remove the eight table cell in all rows in my table. I cant use last since I have rows with just one cell - I want to remove the eight table cell if theres that amount. How Do I do this with jquery?

I started with removing last:

```
$('myTable tr:last').remove();
```

But that obviously didn't work - so Im stuck.

```
<table class="mytable"
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="image"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="image"></td>
   <td class="image"></td>
   <td class="stockinfo"></td>
   <td class="stockinfo"></td>
   <td class="priceinfo"></td>
   <td class="addinfo"></td>
   <td class="addinfo"></td>
   <td class="addinfo"></td> <----remove
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="image"></td>
   <td class="image"></td>
   <td class="stockinfo"></td>
   <td class="stockinfo"></td>
   <td class="priceinfo"></td>
   <td class="addinfo"></td>
   <td class="addinfo"></td>
   <td class="addinfo"></td>  <----remove
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked for the first table row , if i changed it to 8 - how do I make it repeat trough all the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Any of those 2
When you want remove the last element, use the first,
If you want remove specific number, starting from 0 1 2 3 ... use the second

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.mytable tbody tr').each(function(){
            //$(this).find("td:last").remove();
            //$(this).find("td").slice(7).remove()
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted an embarrassingly incorrect answer in comments.  Will try to make up for that with a correct answer here:

```js
    $('tr').each(function() {
      $('td:eq(7)',this).remove()
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="mytable">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="image">DONT REMOVE ME</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="image">X</td>
   <td class="image">X</td>
   <td class="stockinfo">X</td>
   <td class="stockinfo">X</td>
   <td class="priceinfo">X</td>
   <td class="addinfo">X</td>
   <td class="addinfo">X</td>
   <td class="addinfo">REMOVE ME</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="image">X</td>
   <td class="image">X</td>
   <td class="stockinfo">X</td>
   <td class="stockinfo">X</td>
   <td class="priceinfo">X</td>
   <td class="addinfo">X</td>
   <td class="addinfo">X</td>
   <td class="addinfo">REMOVE ME</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to remove the 8th column ( no matter what ), you can use `:nth-child()`

```
$('.mytable tr td:nth-child(8)').remove();
```

But if you are trying to remove the last column ( if even it happens to be the 8th column ) , you could still use `:last` to remove it.

```
$('.mytable tr').each(function()
{
    if($(this).find('td').length > 1)
      $(this).find('td:last').remove();
});
```